# Joomla 1.6 Add Field to registration that requires a certain code in order to go through

Tags: php, joomla1.6

So, I know how to add the field into the form I just can't get it to take the secret code and evaluate it.

Files that I understand to be essential in doing this:

```
/components/com_users/views/registration/tmpl/default.php
/components/com_users/controllers/registration.php
/components/com_users/models/registration.php
/components/com_users/models/forms/registration.xml
```

If I'm not mistaken all I need to find out is where to drop a

```
if( $data['secretcode'] != 'code phrase') {

  return false;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the /components/com_users/models/registration.php file,

I added

```
    // Secret Code Validation
    $secretcode = JRequest::getVar('secretcode', '', 'post', 'string');
    $secretcode2 = 'password';
    $secretcode3 = 'Password';
    if ( $secretcode==$secretcode2 )  {
        return true; 
    } elseif ( $secretcode==$secretcode3 )  {
        return true; 
    } else {
    // Redirect back to the registration screen.
        $this->setMessage('Invalid Secret Code', 'warning');
        $this->setRedirect(JRoute::_('/register/', false));
    return false;
    }
```

right above the form validation.